# Circle in 3D space projected onto 2D

Tags: 3d, geometry

If you have a 2D circle sitting inside a 3D space and you point a virtual camera on it, what will the projection look like? Will it always be an ellipse? Is there a simple way to calculate this ellipse?

How could I write this in java
e.g.

```
class Point3D {
    int x,y,z;
}
class RotatedEllipse extends Ellipse2D.Double {
    double rotation;
}
public static RotatedEllipse circleProjection(Point3D center, int radius, Point3D normalVector, Camera camera) {
    ...
    return new RotatedEllipse(...);
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with programming in any way?

Comment: Fine, I modified my question. Is it acceptable now?

Comment: Showing some code and some effort and putting it into context with your question sure makes it acceptable :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I know found the information I needed here http://chrisjones.id.au/Ellipses/ellipse.html